# how to build a inputConnection between edit text that inside the input method service and the service

Tags: android, android-edittext, ime

I am writing an IME (InputMethodService) and I have an edit text that in the IME itself, but when I want type text into the edit text , the edit text can't get focused and what I type just go to another edit text outside the IME. how can I make the edit text inside the IME work like normal edit text

Answer (score 7):

The way I solved this was by keeping two input connections, one to the original textfield that the user WAS editing, and another to the textfield inside the keyboard. More on the second one later. The first one you should already have, it's where the keyboard sends all of its commands. In my case it was called mIC. So I created another InputConnection variable called mOtherIC on my class that had the InputConnection, and introduced a new method called getIC() which just returned the appropriate one of those two InputConnections to be using at the time (controlled by a boolean in my case, true meant use the textfield in the keyboard, false meant use the textfield that originally presented the keyboard). Every time I had previously accessed mIC, I replaced it with getIC() so it would seamlessly be able to send input to the correct input connection.

The InputConnection for the textfield in the keyboard is the interesting one here, I essentially had to copy the internal Android EditableInputConnection into my own CustomInputConnection class:

```
public class CustomInputConnection extends BaseInputConnection {
    private static final boolean DEBUG = false;
    private static final String TAG = "CustomInputConnection";

    private final TextView mTextView;

    // Keeps track of nested begin/end batch edit to ensure this connection always has a
    // balanced impact on its associated TextView.
    // A negative value means that this connection has been finished by the InputMethodManager.
    private int mBatchEditNesting;

    public CustomInputConnection(TextView textview) {
        super(textview, true);
        mTextView = textview;
    }

    @Override
    public Editable getEditable() {
        TextView tv = mTextView;
        if (tv != null) {
            return tv.getEditableText();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean beginBatchEdit() {
        synchronized(this) {
            if (mBatchEditNesting >= 0) {
                mTextView.beginBatchEdit();
                mBatchEditNesting++;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean endBatchEdit() {
        synchronized(this) {
            if (mBatchEditNesting > 0) {
                // When the connection is reset by the InputMethodManager and reportFinish
                // is called, some endBatchEdit calls may still be asynchronously received from the
                // IME. Do not take these into account, thus ensuring that this IC's final
                // contribution to mTextView's nested batch edit count is zero.
                mTextView.endBatchEdit();
                mBatchEditNesting--;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

//    @Override
//    protected void reportFinish() {
//        super.reportFinish();
//
//        synchronized(this) {
//            while (mBatchEditNesting > 0) {
//                endBatchEdit();
//            }
//            // Will prevent any further calls to begin or endBatchEdit
//            mBatchEditNesting = -1;
//        }
//    }

    @Override
    public boolean clearMetaKeyStates(int states) {
        final Editable content = getEditable();
        if (content == null) return false;
        KeyListener kl = mTextView.getKeyListener();
        if (kl != null) {
            try {
                kl.clearMetaKeyState(mTextView, content, states);
            } catch (AbstractMethodError e) {
                // This is an old listener that doesn't implement the
                // new method.
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean commitCompletion(CompletionInfo text) {
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "commitCompletion " + text);
        mTextView.beginBatchEdit();
        mTextView.onCommitCompletion(text);
        mTextView.endBatchEdit();
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Calls the {@link TextView#onCommitCorrection} method of the associated TextView.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean commitCorrection(CorrectionInfo correctionInfo) {
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "commitCorrection" + correctionInfo);
        mTextView.beginBatchEdit();
        mTextView.onCommitCorrection(correctionInfo);
        mTextView.endBatchEdit();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performEditorAction(int actionCode) {
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "performEditorAction " + actionCode);
        mTextView.onEditorAction(actionCode);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performContextMenuAction(int id) {
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "performContextMenuAction " + id);
        mTextView.beginBatchEdit();
        mTextView.onTextContextMenuItem(id);
        mTextView.endBatchEdit();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public ExtractedText getExtractedText(ExtractedTextRequest request, int flags) {
        if (mTextView != null) {
            ExtractedText et = new ExtractedText();
            if (mTextView.extractText(request, et)) {
                if ((flags&GET_EXTRACTED_TEXT_MONITOR) != 0) {
//                    mTextView.setExtracting(request);
                }
                return et;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performPrivateCommand(String action, Bundle data) {
        mTextView.onPrivateIMECommand(action, data);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean commitText(CharSequence text, int newCursorPosition) {
        if (mTextView == null) {
            return super.commitText(text, newCursorPosition);
        }
        if (text instanceof Spanned) {
            Spanned spanned = ((Spanned) text);
            SuggestionSpan[] spans = spanned.getSpans(0, text.length(), SuggestionSpan.class);
//            mIMM.registerSuggestionSpansForNotification(spans);
        }

//        mTextView.resetErrorChangedFlag();
        boolean success = super.commitText(text, newCursorPosition);
//        mTextView.hideErrorIfUnchanged();

        return success;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean requestCursorUpdates(int cursorUpdateMode) {
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "requestUpdateCursorAnchorInfo " + cursorUpdateMode);

        // It is possible that any other bit is used as a valid flag in a future release.
        // We should reject the entire request in such a case.
        final int KNOWN_FLAGS_MASK = InputConnection.CURSOR_UPDATE_IMMEDIATE |
                InputConnection.CURSOR_UPDATE_MONITOR;
        final int unknownFlags = cursorUpdateMode & ~KNOWN_FLAGS_MASK;
        if (unknownFlags != 0) {
            if (DEBUG) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Rejecting requestUpdateCursorAnchorInfo due to unknown flags." +
                        " cursorUpdateMode=" + cursorUpdateMode +
                        " unknownFlags=" + unknownFlags);
            }
            return false;
        }

        return false;

//        if (mIMM == null) {
//            // In this case, TYPE_CURSOR_ANCHOR_INFO is not handled.
//            // TODO: Return some notification code rather than false to indicate method that
//            // CursorAnchorInfo is temporarily unavailable.
//            return false;
//        }
//        mIMM.setUpdateCursorAnchorInfoMode(cursorUpdateMode);
//        if ((cursorUpdateMode & InputConnection.CURSOR_UPDATE_IMMEDIATE) != 0) {
//            if (mTextView == null) {
//                // In this case, FLAG_CURSOR_ANCHOR_INFO_IMMEDIATE is silently ignored.
//                // TODO: Return some notification code for the input method that indicates
//                // FLAG_CURSOR_ANCHOR_INFO_IMMEDIATE is ignored.
//            } else if (mTextView.isInLayout()) {
//                // In this case, the view hierarchy is currently undergoing a layout pass.
//                // IMM#updateCursorAnchorInfo is supposed to be called soon after the layout
//                // pass is finished.
//            } else {
//                // This will schedule a layout pass of the view tree, and the layout event
//                // eventually triggers IMM#updateCursorAnchorInfo.
//                mTextView.requestLayout();
//            }
//        }
//        return true;
    }
}
```

The class looks pretty bad because I commented out code that wouldn't build, presumably because it accesses internal Android APIs. That said, with a few caveats (cursor probably needs to be set manually when you switch to this input method, capitalization kind of carries-over between the two InputConnections), it works. All you have to do now is at some point set mOtherIC from my first paragraph to a new CustomInputConnection(yourTextfield) where yourTextfield is the textfield inside the keyboard.